# how can i push multiple objects in subdocument array node mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
         //my schema:
                
                const vendorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
              {
                name: {
                  type: String,
                  trim: true,
                  required: true,
                },
            
                contact: {
                  type: Number,
                  required: true,
                  unique: true,
                },
                city: { type: Array, default: [] },
            
                vendorstatus: { type: String, default: "live" },    
            
                 location: [
                   {
                     pincode: { type: Number, required: true },
                     delivery: { type: Number, required: true },
                     dc: { type: String, default: "low" },
                   },
                 ], 
               
              },
              { timestamps: true }
            );
              //  controller to add vendor:
    
        exports.createVendor = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const { contact, city, vendorstatus } = req.body;
        
          if (!contact || !city || !vendorstatus) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error("include all fields");
          }
        
          const vendor = new Vendor({
            name: req.user.name,
            contact,
            city,
            vendorstatus,
          });
        
          await vendor.save((err, vendor) => {
            if (err) {
              return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ error: "Problem while Saving Vendor" + err });
              
            } else {
              return res.json({ sucess: true, vendor });
            }
          });
              //  controller to add location:
                
                exports.createPincode = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
                  const { pincode, delivery, dc } = req.body;
                
                  const vendor = await Vendor.findById(req.params.id); 

         

if (vendor) {
            locations = [{
          pincode: Number(pincode),
          delivery: Number(delivery),
           dc: dc,
           }];
                
                    vendor.location.push(locations);
                
                    vendor.save((err, vendor) => {
                      if (err) {
                        return res
                          .status(400)
                          .json({ error: "Problem while saving locations", err });
                      } else {
                        res.status(201).json({ message: "locations added", vendor });
                      }
                    });
                  } else {
                    res.status(400);
                    throw new Error("Vendor not found");
                  }
                });
            
            
                //in postman i pass this data:
                
                
                { "location": [
                  {
                      "pincode":22222222123,
                      "delivery":300,
                      "dc":"low"
                  },
                   {
                      "pincode":222123,
                      "delivery":300,
                      "dc":"low"
                  },
                   {
                      "pincode":2222123,
                      "delivery":300,
                      "dc":"ow"
                  }
                
                ]
                }
                
                
                
              //  response that i get from postman
                
    {
        "error": "Problem while saving locations",
        "err": {
            "errors": {
                "location.12._id": {
                    "stringValue": "\"[ { pincode: NaN, delivery: NaN, dc: undefined } ]\"",
                    "valueType": "Array",
                    "kind": "ObjectId",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "pincode": null,
                            "delivery": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "path": "_id",
                    "reason": {},
                    "name": "CastError",
                    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ { pincode: NaN, delivery: NaN, dc: undefined } ]\" (type Array) at path \"_id\""
                },
                "location.12.delivery": {
                    "name": "ValidatorError",
                    "message": "Path `delivery` is required.",
                    "properties": {
                        "message": "Path `delivery` is required.",
                        "type": "required",
                        "path": "delivery"
                    },
                    "kind": "required",
                    "path": "delivery"
                },
                "location.12.pincode": {
                    "name": "ValidatorError",
                    "message": "Path `pincode` is required.",
                    "properties": {
                        "message": "Path `pincode` is required.",
                        "type": "required",
                        "path": "pincode"
                    },
                    "kind": "required",
                    "path": "pincode"
                }
            },
            "_message": "Vendor validation failed",
            "name": "ValidationError",
            "message": "Vendor validation failed: location.12._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ { pincode: NaN, delivery: NaN, dc: undefined } ]\" (type Array) at path \"_id\", location.12.delivery: Path `delivery` is required., location.12.pincode: Path `pincode` is required."
        }
    }
```

Where did i go wrong in createPincode controller?

please ignore thisdbhjdbbdasjbjsjhhh hddddddddddddddddd djshdsjds            jdhsd jsdhfsh                fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff fffffffffffffffffffffff fffffffffffffffffffjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj  dddddddddddddddddd ffffffffffffffffff gjgjdfsk fdjfdonf fjfdonfdjofd fajdfknadfsofd dafsjdfsonfds dfsjfjdfsoj

Answer (score 1):

Your location is already an array and you are trying to push array into array. Rather than that just create location object like

```
var location = {
      pincode: Number(pincode),
      delivery: Number(delivery),
      dc: dc,
     }
```

and push this location in the vendor object as

```
vendor.location.push(location)
```

Comment: hi sir after removing [ ]  from location i got this error  
   "message": "Vendor validation failed: location.12.pincode: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" (type number) at path \"pincode\", location.12.delivery: Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" (type number) at path \"delivery\""

Comment: Log the req body and see if your values are correctly reflecting in the logs before you push it to vender object. Looks like the fields are missing there, check the postman request and see if you are adding extra payloads or any other fields before passing the data.

Comment: It clearly says you are receivng NaN in the parameter. So there must be some problem sending the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

this will be solved by using forEach loop or you can use map as well

```
 const vendor = await Vendor.findById(req.params.id);
    const locations = req.body;

    if (vendor) {
      locations.forEach((items) => vendor.location.push(items));

      await vendor.save((err, vendor) => {
        if (err) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: "Problem while saving locations", err });
        } else {
          res.status(201).json({ message: "locations added", vendor });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("Vendor not found");
    }
```